# Appropriate response(s) to a possibly rude 'off-duty' academic staff

Tags: academic-life, soft-skills

In my university, students doing their Phd or Honours are regularly recruited on a part-time basis to assists with students in lab experiments.

As a student in the Math and Physical science, my strength is tilted towards the more mathematical aspect of my studies. On the other hand, I struggle with elementary experimental work. This requires initiative on my part to spend more time in the lab.

In a particular occasion, while working in the lab, a student claiming to be doing his Phd while on causal work as a lab demonstrator offered to assist me in my work.
Note that during this time he was not on duty as a lab demonstrator.

In my observation, a good lab demonstrator is one who provides logical steps for the student to arrive at a conclusion that they are seeking.
When the time came for me to asked for help, he failed to answer my question while actively pass smart-ass condescending remarks.

> Me: "What is the physical significance of xyz? In my lab assignment, I arrived at this equation and solving it should give me what xyz is but I am interested to know what is its physical significance".
>
> Lab demonstrator: "You can't solve that equation? Just do that right? Are you serious? Look, I'm not here to do your work for you".

That event has severely affected my self-esteem. More importantly, he wasn't helpful. Under no circumstance had I any intention of asking him to do my work. His accusation came across as extremely offensive and uncomfortable. However, keeping in mind that he was 'off-duty' and was in the lab as a student and not as a lab demonstrator.

*I stress he is a lab demonstrator only during class hours. At the time of our interaction, he was not functioning as a lab demonstrator. If he is not paid outside his stipulated hours, he is under no obligation to function as a lab demonstrator *

What are appropriate responses under the above event?

Edited to reflect accuracy.

Comment: This is not an answer, and you are right sayin that that was rude, but whenver you ask a question to a lab assistant use the same rules you'd use in asking in StackOverflow: make sure you describe the problem properly and that you showed some research/effort into it. Do no let the "helper" mistake your question with a "do my work" question. Note that I am not saying that you did, just leaving this piece of advise here. Also, don't let someones rudeness affect you.

Comment: It was not the rudeness that affects me. What affected me was the intellectually demeaning comments he made. @AnderBiguri

Comment: Do you know how to solve that equation, or not? If yes, why didn't you tell him right away that he misunderstood your question? If the equation is a really basic one, like a quadratic equation, for which you should have learned the formula long ago, the comment seems a bit blunt but not completely out of line.

Comment: Yes it is a very basic one which I could solve by hand or by computer-easier than quadratic equation. He was not answering my question in the OP and constantly going on with smart-ass comments leaving me no time to respond without interrupting. Once he was done, he returned to his seat. I offered a "thank you" from across my seat but he was unresponsive.I didn't felt any further interaction with this person is warranted. @FedericoPoloni

Comment: I too had argues with different lab assistants, the best action would be to let it go, don't spend psychic energy on people that are not worth it, t is something that doesn't affect you, trust more on your capabilities.

Comment: So some jerk offers to help you and then decides to be a jerk instead. (His job is irrelevant.) Burn him in effigy and move on with your life. If he offers to "help" again, look him square in the eye and say no, possibly prefixed by a four-letter epithet.

Answer (score 2):

*What are appropriate responses under the above event?*

That depends whether or not he is your direct superior, I must say I didn't quite get that from your question. You state that he is a lab demonstrator, but was not "on duty" at the time of the incident.

In the general case, you will meet many condescending people throughout your life. So my first suggestion is to start developing a thicker skin and just shrugging it off.

You should also keep in mind that he told you a lot about his personality. So, your lesson is to keep the communication with this individual to a minimum. Since he offered you help, but then failed to be constructive and was insulting and disrupting instead, you shouldn't accept (or ask for) help from him anymore. If he "offers his help" again, politely decline "I can manage on my own, thank you.". If he disrupts your work by trying to force his assistance, then that is an issue for the lab supervisor and you should bring the case to them.

If he is, or is assigned in the future to be, your lab demonstrator, i.e. "on duty" as you said, and behaves in a similar manner, this is also something that you should bring to the lab supervisor. Avoid "paying him in kind", i.e. engaging in an open confrontation with him, though. You gain nothing by it, you'll probably just end up demeaning yourself to the same level as he.

Comment: I have edited the OP to reflect greater accuracies in my post. He is a *causal* lab demonstrator on days where he has classes. On days without, he isn't paid and thus not functioning as a lab demonstrator.